# Activity Stream filtering by context in Jira dashboard

Tags: jira

I don't want the Activity Stream widget for the dashboard to show the entire application, only the sub-project I am working on (i.e. the project context). Is this possible, if so how do I configure it?

This is an installation of Jira 4.4 with Greenhopper integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a filter to the Activity Stream for the project you're interested in. You would need to edit the Activity Stream configuration, check the box for `Apply filters`, add the Project filter and select your project in the list.

See the JIRA 4.4 Activity Stream documentation for a screen shot and more details:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA044/Adding+the+Activity+Stream+Gadget